# Select font when converting .txt to .pdf from command line

Tags: pdf, font, file-conversion, text

I often need to convert text files to PDF from the command line. I currently use `enscript`, `a2pdf`, `cupsfilter`, etc. The feature I'm missing is the ability to use an OS X font instead of one of the "standard Unix" fonts. I'm particularly interested in the AmericanTypewriter font. Is there an existing tool to do that or perhaps an Apple Script? If not, are there any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [solution is to create an afm version of the font you want to use](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TT-Debian-5.html) which is American-typewriter for the `enscript` program to create with.

What you need to do is grab a copy of the  AmericanTypewriter font. Which is located at `/Library/Fonts/AmericanTypewriter.ttc`

Next obtain and run the program `ttf2pt1`.  Copy the output file that you can name atw.afm to enscript's afm directory located at `/usr/share/enscript/afm`.

Edit the "font.map" file located in `/usr/share/enscript/afm`

Add in the **AmericanTypewriter** font to the list.

```
AmericanTypewriter         atw
AvantGarde-Demi            agd
...                        ...
```

Lastly re-run the enscript and choose the new font, process as you would normally after that but now including the AmericanTypewriter font.

```
enscript -f "AmericanTypewriter12" -p postScriptOutputfile yourFile.txt
```

Comment: A modification of your procedure worked for me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! `ttf2afm` did not want to convert a `ttc` file (which, as I understand, is a collection of `ttf` fonts). I needed to use `ttf2pt1` and the procedure outline here: http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/svn/emacswiki/emacswikipages/EnscriptPrint

Comment: Glad you were able to get it work, I updated the answer above accordingly to reflect your finding.

Answer (score 1):

https://pandoc.org/ can convert from text to PDF and has many options, also to configure fonts.
Basic invocation:

```
pandoc input.txt -o output.pdf
```

Comment: Are there any already installed applications that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some basic LaTeX knowledge (and a working LaTeX installation), I strongly recommend you to take a look at Fletcher Penney's [Multimarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/), an extended Markdown interpreter, which has a great customizable feature of converting text files to `.tex` –from there, it's obviously a short step to a beautiful `.pdf` document formatted in accordance with your needs.

Check Chapter 5 of the Multimarkdown [manual](http://fletcher.github.com/peg-multimarkdown/mmd-manual.pdf) on how to customize LaTeX output – you will need to install both Multimarkdown ([installer](https://github.com/downloads/fletcher/peg-multimarkdown/MultiMarkdown-Mac-3.5.pkg.zip)) and the [support files](https://github.com/downloads/fletcher/peg-multimarkdown/MultiMarkdown-Support-Mac-3.5.pkg.zip).

Then, nothing prevents you from using `XeTeX` instead of `LaTeX`, which will allow you to use the [fontspec](http://www.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) package to select any font installed on your system. I haven't actually tried, but it should be fairly easy to create a simple custom LaTeX template for Multimarkdown (without the Author & Title information and all that) to produce PDF output in the font of your choice.

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with Markdown and LaTeX but it's not an option for me as I need to convert the files without changing them. And they predate Markdown.